# Multiple Column Percent of Total

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID  PERIOD_1    PERIOD_2    PERIOD_3
0   6           5           5
1   120         124         85
2   183         159         99
3   60          42          27
4   24          19          8
5   1
```

I'm using Oracle, and there are only ever these 6 rows to this dataset.

Using SQL, how can I put "Percent of Total" columns for each of the Periods - so that in the end there will be additional PERIOD_1_PERC, PERIOD_2_PERC, AND PERIOD_3_PERC columns?

Comment: Please show us the full example and explain to us what you've already tried.

Comment: And what is the logic for the percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret "percent of period" as the proportion within each column.  That would use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       period_1 / sum(period_1) over () as period_1_perc,
       period_2 / sum(period_2) over () as period_2_perc,
       period_3 / sum(period_3) over () as period_3_perc
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you yes this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This seems fairly straightforward; you need to calculate the total for each row, taking nulls into account, divide each period's value by that, multiply by 100, and probably round (or floor/ceil/trunc) the result to some number of decimal places:

```
select id, period_1, period_2, period_3,
  nvl(period_1, 0) + nvl(period_2, 0) + nvl(period_3, 0) as total,
  round(100 * period_1 / (nvl(period_1, 0) + nvl(period_2, 0) + nvl(period_3, 0)), 2) as period_1_perc,
  round(100 * period_2 / (nvl(period_1, 0) + nvl(period_2, 0) + nvl(period_3, 0)), 2) as period_2_perc,
  round(100 * period_3 / (nvl(period_1, 0) + nvl(period_2, 0) + nvl(period_3, 0)), 2) as period_3_perc
from your_table;
```

You don't have to show the total of course, but it might be useful. Or if you don't want to repeat the total calculation you can use a CTE or inline view:

```
select id, period_1, period_2, period_3,
  round(100 * period_1 / total, 2) as period_1_perc,
  round(100 * period_2 / total, 2) as period_2_perc,
  round(100 * period_3 / total, 2) as period_3_perc
from (
  select id, period_1, period_2, period_3,
    nvl(period_1, 0) + nvl(period_2, 0) + nvl(period_3, 0) as total
  from your_table
);
```

```
ID PERIOD_1 PERIOD_2 PERIOD_3 PERIOD_1_PERC PERIOD_2_PERC PERIOD_3_PERC
-- -------- -------- -------- ------------- ------------- -------------
 0        6        5        5          37.5         31.25         31.25
 1      120      124       85         36.47         37.69         25.84
 2      183      159       99          41.5         36.05         22.45
 3       60       42       27         46.51         32.56         20.93
 4       24       19        8         47.06         37.25         15.69
 5        1                             100
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=712a6b6e45eec61fd2a504d313d3be18)